# Vectorizing Numpy for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently trying to vectorize a few operations in NumPy. s is a very large number (10000) and X represents a numpy array with around 1200000

```
for element1 in range(1,s+1):
    d = np.zeros(s)
    for element2 in range(1,s+1):
        d[element2-1] =  norm(np.subtract(X[0:n,element1],X[0:n,element2]))
```

I'm trying to rewrite this without using for loops but I can't think of a way. One method of trying involves using zip and np.tile, but that yields wrong results.

Comment: What is `norm`?

Comment: Norm is a calc in linalg library.

Comment: Don't you want `d` for every `element1`? You don't seem to store `d` there.

Comment: Every time the first for loop runs, d becomes an np array of zeros. In the second for loop, elements of d are set equal to values based on the linalg.norm calculation and the X array. I later use d for further operations, but this part of the code is running the longest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are basically euclidean distances on a slice off the input array -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist, squareform

X_slice = X[0:n,1:s+1]
d_all = squareform(pdist(X_slice.T))
```

Thus, inside the first loop, it would be just a slice from the output `d_all` that could be re-used as `d`, like so -

```
for element1 in range(1,s+1):
    d = d_all[element1-1, :]
```